# How to draw a semicircle in Python turtle only

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

How to draw a semi circle(half circle) in python turtle only?

I can only use Python turtle. I have try looking for resouces but no luck on finding ones that only use Python turtle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
t.left(90)
for x in range(180):
    t.forward(1)
    t.right(1)
t.right(90)
t.forward(115)
```

Comment: How did you come up with the 118 diameter?  Since the turtle moves forward 1 each time, I'd expect a diameter of 360 circumference / math.pi which is closer to 115 which works fine -- 118 overshoots (if you hide the turtle itself.)

Comment: I have no idea @cdlane. It was 2 years ago. I'll edit to 115.

Answer (score 24):

See [Python turtle reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) on circle.
For example, for a semi-circle with radius 100 it would be:

```
import turtle
turtle.circle(100,180)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it just using circle. `turtle.circle(radius, extent,steps)` eg.

```py
turtle.circle(50,180) # - step is optional
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, a way to create a semicircle with turtle using *stamping* instead of *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

DIAMETER = 200
STAMP_SIZE = 20
BACKGROUND = screen.bgcolor()

yertle = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
yertle.penup()

yertle.shapesize(DIAMETER / STAMP_SIZE)
yertle.color('black', BACKGROUND)  # drop second argument for a filled semicircle
yertle.stamp()

yertle.shape('square')
yertle.shapesize(stretch_len=(DIAMETER / 2) / STAMP_SIZE)
yertle.color(BACKGROUND)
yertle.forward(DIAMETER / 4)
yertle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

It has its obvious shortcomings but sometimes it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

for drawing a semicircle in python turtle is very simple all you have to do is

```
import turtle
tom=turtle.Turtle()
tom.circle(100,180)
```

for the circle, the first digit is the radius of the circle and the second one is the amount that you want to draw it for a semicircle you can use 180 degrees as shown in the code above but you can do a quarter of a circle then if you want to connect the semicircle just turn left then for forward the radius*2

Answer (score 0):

If You also want a line under the semicircle(like a moon), Try this

```py
import turtle
turtle.circle(100, 180) #Draws a circle with 180 degrees and 100 pixels radius(a half circle)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200)
```